# Como lançar minhas próprias exceções com o PDO?

Tags: php, exceção, pdoexception

Ao executar a linha abaixo, no construtor da minha classe de acesso ao banco de dados:

```php
$this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

O PDO passará a reportar erros lançando exceções do tipo `PDOException`. Existe alguma configuração para que eu possa fazê-lo lançar minha `DatabaseException`?

Não queria ter que fazer `try catch()` com um `throw new DatabaseException()` em tudo quanto é método que tem nessa minha classe de acesso ao banco, que já ela estende outra classe com os métodos concretos, que é de um framework.

**EDIT:** A minha classe Database, cujos métodos poderão lançar a `DatabaseException`, estende o DAO *catfan/medoo* que é carregado via `Composer`. Logo, não devo mexer na estrutura da classe original, já que esta será sempre atualizada. Por isso, não queria criar um forte dependência como um Proxy.

Comment: Não tenho uma resposta definitiva ainda, mas olhando os fontes do [`PDO`](http://pear.php.net/package/Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_PDO/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_PDO__Structures_DataGrid_DataSource_PDO-0.2.0StructuresDataGridDataSourcePDO.php.html) e do [`PEAR::raiseError`](http://pear.php.net/package/PEAR/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_PEAR__PEAR-1.9.4PEAR.php.html#a472) - em particular na linha `$ec = $this->_error_class;` - eu suspeito que seja possível sim... Amanhã, se ninguém achar uma solução, volto a investigar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz algumas pesquisas e analisei a [documentação](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) [oficial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php). Parece não ser possível substituir a exceção `PDOException` por uma customizada através de alguma configuração simples.

Porém, pensei em algumas formas de contornar o problema. Talvez alguma se adapte ao seu caso.

## Capturar a exceção globalmente

Uma solução simplista e limitada, caso a exceção possa ser tratada globalmente, seria usar a função [`set_exception_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) para capturar exceções não tratadas por blocos `try/catch`.

O exemplo abaixo captura as exceções e verifica se é do tipo `PDOException`. Se for, exibe uma mensagem e permite que o programa continue executando. Caso contrário relança a exceção.

```php
function pdoExceptionHandler($e) {
    if ($e instanceof PDOException) {
        echo 'Erro PDO Capturado!';
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
set_exception_handler("pdoExceptionHandler");
```

Veja o exemplo funcional no [codepad](http://codepad.org/sEhNYcFU).

Essa solução é limitada porque a função *handler* só é executada se a exceção não for capturada em nenhum lugar por um `catch`.

## Encapsular o PDO

Outra abordagem seria não usar as classes do PDO diretamente, mas criar *wrappers* para abstrair suas funcionalidades.

### Encapsulamento com herança

A primeira abordagem é criar classes que herdem do PDO original e sobrescrevam os métodos necessários, acrescentando o tratamento `try/catch` e relançando a exceção customizada. Assim você faz o tratamento uma vez e reusa em todos os acessos a banco que precisar.

[Nesta pergunta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646719/call-database-wrapper-in-another-class), encontrei um exemplo parecido com isso, isto é, uma classe abstrai o uso do PDO. Note que o autor da pergunta afirma que há um problema ao fechar a conexão com essa classe. Infelizmente me falta um ambiente para testar e validar o funcionamento dela. Se quiser usá-la como base para desenvolver a sua, segue o código:

```php
class Database extends PDO {
    private $driver = "mysql";
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $dbname = "dbname";
    private $user = "user";
    private $pass = "pass";
    private $connect = false;
    private $error = "";
    private $stmt = "";

    public function __construct() {
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try {
            parent::__construct($this->driver.":host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->dbname, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
        $this->connect = true;
    }

    public function run($statement, $bind = array()) {
        try {
            $this->stmt = $this->prepare($statement);
            $this->stmt->execute($bind);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }

    }

    public function fetchAssoc() {
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    public function rowCount() {
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }

    public function getErrorMessage() {
        return $this->error;
    }

    public function isOpen() {
        return $this->connect;
    }

    public function close() {
        //$this->connect = false;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->connect = false;
    }
}
```

### Encapsulamento com um *proxy*

Outra abordagem seria criar uma classe que funcionaria como um *proxy* para o PDO verdadeiro. Ela teria um atributo que faz referência ao PDO e métodos com as mesmas assinaturas que do PDO, os quais delegam a execução para o PDO, mas tratam a exceção devidamente.

Uma técnica que ajudaria nesta última abordagem para não precisar criar todos os métodos manualmente seria usar os *triggers* `__call` e `__callStatic` (ver [documentação](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)). Com eles você consegue delegar as chamadas normais e estáticas a métodos sem precisar criar cada método, de forma dinâmica e fazendo o tratamento em um só ponto.

Quando uma classe possui um método `__call($name, $arguments)`, por exemplo, e você chama um método qualquer nessa classe, mesmo que o método **não esteja declarado**, o PHP vai executar o `__call` passando o nome do método chamado (`$name`) e os parâmetros em um array (`$arguments`). É uma funcionalidade muito legal do PHP!

Fiz uma implementação básica

```php
class MyPDO {
    private $pdo = null;
    function __construct($url, $user, $pw) {
        $this->pdo = new PDO($url, $user, $pw);
    }
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        try {
            call_user_func_array(array($this->pdo, $name), $arguments);
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            throw new DataBaseException('database error');
        }
    }
}
```

Veja um [exemplo funcional aqui](http://codepad.org/LCuqm1J6).

### Encapsulando com uma biblioteca

Encontrei um projeto chamado [php-pdo-wrapper-class](https://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class/) que visa facilitar um pouco o uso do PDO. Além de trazer alguns métodos úteis, ela possui um método chamado [`setErrorCallbackFunction()`](http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/#setErrorCallbackFunction) que talvez resolva seu problema sem você precisar criar sua própria solução.

Comment: Isso faria parte de um framework que construo, mas não vejo uma única saída além de rescrever todos os métodos , que ainda preze pela praticidade dessa aplicação. O padrão Proxy foi quem chegou mais perto de funcionar.